# 500% zoom: content center 3

Tags: html, css

I wanted my left right content be centered after zooming in 500% plus on the web page, I have tried so many ways, but still don't have an answer can anyone give me a hand here please.

copy and paste to make a new webpage, you can't see if you paste on fiddle or codewall.

html:

```
<body>
    <div id="lower_body">
        <h1>center content</h1>
        <div id="outer_warpper">
           <div id="outer">
               <div id="left"><h1>left</h1></div>    
               <div id="right"><h1>right</h1></div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </body>
```

CSS:

```
#lower-body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#outer_warpper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-top: 2%;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#outer {
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table;
    margin:0px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#right { 
    width: 450px;
    height: 350px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: red;
}
#left{
    width: 450px;
    height: 350px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: grey;
}

img{
widht:100%;
height:100%;
}

h1{
    text-align: center;
}
```

as you can see when it reach 500% (ctrl+mouse scroll), the left and right text is not in the center any more, because it push to left somehow.

can one help me make it? Thank for helping. I had tried the width:% also dont work, some one say it need to be done in @media.

Comment: would we copy and paste the code to the fiddle........are we hungry to do that?

Comment: jsfiddle can be used for that... just add `/show` at the end of fiddle url.. Here is the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Njqj9/show/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a normal behavior...

Your two divs are positioned relatively next to each other. If they can't fit the one next to the other then the second one will reposition itself underneath the first one...

if you REALLY want to make it work on 500% zoom what you can do is:

1. Resize your divs **[(example)](http://jsfiddle.net/Njqj9/4/show/)**
2. Use % widths **[(example2)](http://jsfiddle.net/Njqj9/7/show/)**

Personally i would go with my second example. The choice though is yours (depending always on why you need to achieve this)

PS: % width was not working because you were using `display:table;` on the `#outer` div

Comment: thank for helping , nope i wanted the right box to be pushed down , my intention is to make the left and right zoomed into center , whice every thing work fine but once is reached 300%-500% ,it some how push to left, you can the left right text is not at center anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem or even a bug, it's just the normal behavior of the browser. It's just too much zoom to keep any consistency. I think 400% is the max in this case. If you try it in FireFox, you won't get this problem because it doesn't go till 500%.

It's pretty good to be concerned about zooming in a web page, but 500% is just too much to any page work fine.